# I have a problem in log likelihood which I wrote for custom distribution

Tags: distributions, parameters

I have a custom distribution and data as follows

```
 i={42, 180, 35, 392, 63, 230, 112, 281, 42, 28, 42, 120, 148, 16, 310, 28, 68, 336, 21.5, 50, 19, 30, 12, 120, 140, 170, 17, 115, 31, 21,  52, 164, 225, 225, 151, 60, 200, 46, 210, 14};
MO = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF",  1 - ((\[Alpha]*E^-x)/(1 - (1 - \[Alpha])*E^-x))}, {x,  0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> {\[Alpha] > 0}]
```

i used maximum likelihood as follow

```
mlmo = FindDistributionParameters[i, MO, ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
```

and the output was as follows

```
{\[Alpha] -> 4.57761*10^7}
```

When I used loglikelihood as follow the results was as follows

```
LogLikelihood[MO, {42, 180, 35, 392, 63, 230, 112, 281, 42, 28, 42, 120, 148, 16, 310, 28, 68, 336, 21.5, 50, 19, 30, 12, 120, 140, 170, 17, 115, 31, 21, 52, 164, 225, 225, 151, 60, 200, 46, 210,  14}] /.  {\[Alpha] -> 4.57761*10^7}
```

The output was -3885.87. I used this code and wrote log likelihood manual to get parameter

```
bbb = Total[logpdf = (Log[PDF[MOE, i]])]
Dbal = D[bbb, \[Alpha]]
b = FindRoot[Dbal, {\[Alpha], 1}]
```

This the output

[image: 333]

This is the loglikelihood

```
LogLikelihood[MOE, {42, 180, 35, 392, 63, 230, 112, 281, 42, 28, 42, 120, 148, 16,310, 28, 68, 336, 21.5, 50, 19, 30, 12, 120, 140, 170, 17, 115,  31, 21, 52, 164, 225, 225, 151, 60, 200, 46, 210, 14}] /. {\[Alpha] -> 2.2402116078266955`*^21}
```

The output is better: -3283.72
Now, what does the output mean?
[image]

Comment: Is `MOE` the same as `MO`? I assume it is. Your `i` contains one inexact number, namely `21.5`. Please replace it by the exact number `215/10`. I assume you do that.
I think the warnings appear because you evaluate `E^x` for large `x` such as `Max[i]==392`, which generates huge (!) numbers. It seems that you can avoid the warning using something like `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision=1000}, FindRoot[Dbal,{\[Alpha],1}, WorkingPrecision->1000, MaxIterations->1000]]//N`. But, more generally, please check if you are on the right track, I do not know the background of this calculation.

Comment: Thanks, more I wanted it really

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**  Added why the candidate distribution almost certainly didn't generate the observed data.

While there are numeric stability issues with estimating $\alpha$ given your data and candidate distribution, the main issue is that candidate distribution will not fit your data.

Consider the difference between the 99.5% and 0.5% quantiles (i.e., the width of the middle 99% of the data:

```
MO = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", 1 - ((α*E^-x)/(1 - (1 - α)*E^-x))},
   {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {α > 0}];
width = Quantile[MO, 995/1000] - Quantile[MO, 5/1000]
(* -Log[(199 + α)/199] + Log[1 + 199 α] *)
(* 10.5866 *)
```

The limit of the width of the middle 99% of the data as $\alpha -> \infty$ is

```
Limit[width, α -> ∞] // N
(* 10.5866 *)
```

The range of your data is

```
Max[i] - Min[i]
(* 380 *)
```

380 is much, much larger than 10.5866 and it is extremely unlikely that the candidate distribution could possibly the source of the data.

Essentially your distribution is missing a scaling parameter.  $x$ needs to be divided by a constant.

```
i = {42, 180, 35, 392, 63, 230, 112, 281, 42, 28, 42, 120, 148, 16, 
   310, 28, 68, 336, 21.5, 50, 19, 30, 12, 120, 140, 170, 17, 115, 31,
    21, 52, 164, 225, 225, 151, 60, 200, 46, 210, 14};
MO = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", 1 - ((α*E^-(x/β))/(1 - (1 - α)*E^-(x/β)))}, 
  {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {α > 0, β > 0}]
mle = FindDistributionParameters[i, MO, ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
(* {α -> 1.3236, β -> 99.906} *)

Show[Histogram[i, {50}, "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[MO /. mle, x], {x, 0, 400}]]
```

[image: Histogram and fit]

You might want to question whoever gave you that candidate distribution.